# Problems with P. Hall theorem proof (The problem involves the use of Frattini's argument)

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

### Theorem

*Let G be a solvable group of order $ab$, where $(a,b)=1$. Then $G$ contains at least one subgroup of order $a$, and any two such are conjugate.*

### Details

The proof the book presents involves two cases.

- Case 1: There exist a normal subgroup $H$ of order $a_1b_1$ where $a_1|a$, $b_1|b$ and $b_1<b$
- Case 2: For all normal subgroups $H$ of order $a_1b_1$ where $a_1|a$ and $b_1|b$ then $b_1=b$.

I have already gone through proving case 1 by induction.  The author assuming part two and using some facts we proved in the past arrives at the fact that case 2 can be rewritten in the form

- Case 2(rewrite): $G$ has a unique minimal normal subgroup $H$ (and $H$ is an abelian group of order $p^n$ and index prime to $p$)

With this the author constructs a new normal subgroup of $G$, by defining that subgroup $K=\varphi^{-1}(K^*)$ where $\varphi$ is the natural map and $K^*$ is a minimal normal subgroup of $G/H$. It is assumed that $|K^*|=q^m$. The author then makes the claim that I am now trying to prove which is ( If $S\in Syl_q(K)$ then $|N_G(S)|=a$.

### Problem

**The author lets $N^*=N_G(S)$ and $N=K\cap N^*$ he then states that using the Frattini argument shows that $K=HN$**. While at first I thought I understood why this was true (Seeing as $H\lhd K$ and $N=N_K(S)$) but a closer look at the Frattini argument shows that $S\subset H$ for the frattini argument to work. The author then later goes on to say (Further in the proof ) that ***if $k\in K$ then $k=hs$, where $h\in H$ and $s\in S$.* But that statement would imply that $K=HS$, why would that be?**

Comment: what is the name of the book that you used and the name of the author?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this helps: in fact it is true that $K=HS$. Why? Well, $S \in Syl_q(K)$, hence $HS/H$ is a Sylow $q$-subgroup of $G/H$. Since $K/H$ is a (minimal) *normal* $q$-subgroup of $G/H$, by Sylow it must be contained in all Sylow $q$-subgroups of $G/H$, so $K/H \subseteq HS/H$, which gives $K \subseteq HS$. Conversely $H \subseteq K$ and $S \subseteq K$, so $HS \subseteq K$.

Now apply Frattini: $S \in Syl_q(K)$ and $K \unlhd G$, so $G=N_G(S)K=KN^*=HN_G(S)$.